# How to track that a request is handled by which view in django project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a django project which consists of multiple apps and every app has its separate urls.py file.
Now when we send a request in a browser, how can we track that the request is handled by which view in our project?

e.g. We send a request with this url:
http://mywebsite.com:8000/item?id=2

In server , we can see the request as:
"GET /item?id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200
How can we track that this request is handled by which view?

Comment: modify middleware

Answer (score 0):

When you use several urls.py to need to link those in the main URLCONF which is stated in `settings.py` (usually this is in the same folder like your settings file)

Usually, we put each app under a separate URL like

```
urlpatterns[
           ('users/', include('users.urls'),
           ('products/', include('products.urls')
           ]
```

So if you want to reach 'add' in users, the user shall be '/users/add/'